# argmax aggregation and select n biggest values in altair

Tags: python, data-visualization, altair

I am working on this simple example, based on data where "year" has been parsed as a date (am not sure this is the source of problem #1)

```
alt.Chart(data).mark_bar(size=10).encode(
    # alt.X("population", aggregate={"argmax": "year"}),
    alt.X("max(population)"),
    alt.Y("country", sort="-x"),
    alt.Color("continent"),
).transform_filter("datum.population > 1e8").properties(width=400, height=200)
```

[image]

The output is almost ok. What I would like is :

1. use the `argmax` aggregation to take the latest population value rather than the biggest. If I use the line in comment, the plot is empty
2. replace the `transform_filter` with a selection of the k (=10?) most populated countries.
3. how to have proper decimal separators in the tooltip as well? Can we have "100 millions" instead of "100,000,000" in the x-axis?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. there appears to be a vega-lite bug when using the bar mark with an argmax aggregate in the encoding. You can work around this by using an [aggregate transform](https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/transform/aggregate.html).
2. You can use a [window transform](https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/transform/window.html) to compute the rank, and then filter on this, as demonstrated in the [Top K Items](https://altair-viz.github.io/gallery/top_k_items.html) example.
3. Axis label formats can be specified using specifiers documented in the [d3-format](https://github.com/d3/d3-format#locale_format) package.

Putting this all together & using some fake data for demonstration, this is an example of the approach you might use:

```python
import altair as alt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = pd.DataFrame({
    'continent': 6 * ['Europe'] + 6 * ['Asia'],
    'country': 3 * ['Germany'] + 3 * ['Spain'] + 3 * ['China'] + 3 * ['Japan'],
    'year': 4 * [2018, 2019, 2020],
    'population': np.random.randint(1E7, 1.2E8, 12),
})

alt.Chart(data).mark_bar(size=10).transform_aggregate(
    most_recent_year='argmax(population)',
    groupby=['country', 'continent']
).transform_calculate(
    population='datum.most_recent_year.population'
).transform_window(
    rank='rank(population)',
    sort=[alt.SortField('population', order='descending')]
).transform_filter(
    alt.datum.rank <= 3  
).encode(
    alt.X("population:Q", axis=alt.Axis(format='~s')),
    alt.Y("country:N", sort="-x"),
    alt.Color("continent:N"),
)
```

[image]